# Repetitive Tic-Tac-Toe AI game with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, ai

I have a text based Tic-Tac-Toe game with a simple AI element that will take winning moves and block losing moves. The one piece of criticism I received was that I was 'hard coding' too much. I can see this, for example, in `check_computer_win`. How can I use a dictionary to cut down on hard coding? What are some of the best ways I can solve my repetition problem?

```
#! python

""" This my Tic Tac Toe game with python.

2019-01-10

"""

import random
import sys

board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
open_boxes = 9
human_letter = ''
opp_letter = ''
winner = False
can_block = False

def choose_letter():  
    global human_letter
    global opp_letter
    human_letter = input('Please choose "x" or "o": ').lower()
    if human_letter == 'x':
        opp_letter = 'o'
    elif human_letter == 'o':
        opp_letter = 'x'
    else:
        print('Please choose again.')
        choose_letter()

def show_board():
    print (board[0], '|', board[1], '|', board[2])
    print ("----------")
    print (board[3], '|', board[4], '|', board[5])
    print ("----------")
    print (board[6], '|', board[7], '|', board[8])
    print (" ")

def checkLine(char, first, second, third):
    if board[first] == char and board[second] == char and board[third] == char:
        return True

def checkAll(char):
    if checkLine(char,0,1,2):
        return True
    if checkLine(char,3,4,5):
        return True
    if checkLine(char,6,7,8):
        return True
    if checkLine(char,0,3,6):
        return True
    if checkLine(char,1,4,7):
        return True
    if checkLine(char,2,5,8):
        return True
    if checkLine(char,0,4,8):
        return True
    if checkLine(char,2,4,6):
        return True

def computer_move():
        global open_boxes
        if open_boxes > 0:
            check_computer_win()
            if not winner:
                block_human_win()
                if not can_block:
                    opp_move = random.randint(0,8)
                    if board[opp_move] != 'o' and board[opp_move] != 'x':
                        open_boxes -= 1
                        board[opp_move] = opp_letter
                        print('Computer\'s turn')
                        print('Computer is thinking...')
                        print('\n')
                        show_board()            
                    else:
                        computer_move()
        else:
            print('--DRAW--')
            play_again()

def check_computer_win():
    #check for a top horizontal win
    if board[0] == opp_letter and board[1] == opp_letter:
        if board[2] != human_letter:
            board[2] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[0] == opp_letter and board[2] == opp_letter:
        if board[1] != human_letter:
            board[1] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[1] == opp_letter and board[2] == opp_letter:
        if board[0] != human_letter:
            board[0] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    #check for a middle horizontal win
    if board[3] == opp_letter and board[4] == opp_letter:
        if board[5] != human_letter:
            board[5] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[3] == opp_letter and board[5] == opp_letter:
        if board[4] != human_letter:
            board[4] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[4] == opp_letter and board[5] == opp_letter:
        if board[3] != human_letter:
            board[3] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    #check for a bottom horizontal win
    if board[6] == opp_letter and board[7] == opp_letter:
        if board[8] != human_letter:
            board[8] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[6] == opp_letter and board[8] == opp_letter:
        if board[7] != human_letter:
            board[7] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[7] == opp_letter and board[8] == opp_letter:
        if board[6] != human_letter:
            board[6] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    #check for a left vertical win
    if board[0] == opp_letter and board[3] == opp_letter:
        if board[6] != human_letter:
            board[6] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[0] == opp_letter and board[6] == opp_letter:
        if board[3] != human_letter:
            board[3] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[3] == opp_letter and board[6] == opp_letter:
        if board[0] != human_letter:
            board[0] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    #check for a left vertical win
    if board[0] == opp_letter and board[3] == opp_letter:
        if board[6] != human_letter:
            board[6] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[0] == opp_letter and board[6] == opp_letter:
        if board[3] != human_letter:
            board[3] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[3] == opp_letter and board[6] == opp_letter:
        if board[0] != human_letter:
            board[0] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    #check for a middle vertical win
    if board[1] == opp_letter and board[4] == opp_letter:
        if board[7] != human_letter:
            board[7] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[1] == opp_letter and board[7] == opp_letter:
        if board[4] != human_letter:
            board[4] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[4] == opp_letter and board[7] == opp_letter:
        if board[1] != human_letter:
            board[1] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    #check for a right vertical win
    if board[2] == opp_letter and board[5] == opp_letter:
        if board[8] != human_letter:
            board[8] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[2] == opp_letter and board[8] == opp_letter:
        if board[5] != human_letter:
            board[5] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[5] == opp_letter and board[8] == opp_letter:
        if board[2] != human_letter:
            board[2] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    #check for a left to right diagonal win
    if board[0] == opp_letter and board[4] == opp_letter:
        if board[8] != human_letter:
            board[8] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[4] == opp_letter and board[8] == opp_letter:
       if board[0] != human_letter:
            board[0] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again() 
    if board[0] == opp_letter and board[8] == opp_letter:
        if board[4] != human_letter:
            board[4] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    #check for a right to left diagonal win
    if board[2] == opp_letter and board[4] == opp_letter:
        if board[6] != human_letter:
            board[6] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[4] == opp_letter and board[6] == opp_letter:
        if board[2] != human_letter:
            board[2] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()
    if board[2] == opp_letter and board[6] == opp_letter:
        if board[4] != human_letter:
            board[4] = opp_letter
            winner = True
            print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
            show_board()
            play_again()

def block_human_win():
    global open_boxes
    #Block top horizontal win
    if board[0] == human_letter and board[1] == human_letter:
        if board[2] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[2] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[0] == human_letter and board[2] == human_letter:
        if board[1] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[1] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[1] == human_letter and board[2] == human_letter:
        if board[0] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[0] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    #Block middle horizontal win
    if board[3] == human_letter and board[4] == human_letter:
        if board[5] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[5] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[3] == human_letter and board[5] == human_letter:
        if board[4] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[4] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[4] == human_letter and board[5] == human_letter:
        if board[3] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[3] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    #Block bottom horizontal win
    if board[6] == human_letter and board[7] == human_letter:
        if board[8] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[8] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[6] == human_letter and board[8] == human_letter:
        if board[7] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[7] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[7] == human_letter and board[8] == human_letter:
        if board[6] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[6] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    #Block left vertical win
    if board[0] == human_letter and board[3] == human_letter:
        if board[6] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[6] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[0] == human_letter and board[6] == human_letter:
        if board[3] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[3] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[3] == human_letter and board[6] == human_letter:
        if board[0] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[0] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    #Block middle vertical win
    if board[1] == human_letter and board[4] == human_letter:
        if board[7] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[7] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[1] == human_letter and board[7] == human_letter:
        if board[4] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[4] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[4] == human_letter and board[7] == human_letter:
        if board[1] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[1] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    #Block right vertical win
    if board[2] == human_letter and board[5] == human_letter:
        if board[8] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[8] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[2] == human_letter and board[8] == human_letter:
        if board[5] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[5] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[5] == human_letter and board[8] == human_letter:
        if board[2] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[2] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    #Block left to right diagonal win
    if board[0] == human_letter and board[4] == human_letter:
        if board[8] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[8] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[0] == human_letter and board[8] == human_letter:
        if board[4] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[4] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[4] == human_letter and board[8] == human_letter:
        if board[0] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[0] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    #Block right to left diagonal win
    if board[2] == human_letter and board[4] == human_letter:
        if board[6] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[6] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[2] == human_letter and board[6] == human_letter:
        if board[4] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[4] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()
    if board[4] == human_letter and board[6] == human_letter:
        if board[2] != opp_letter:
            can_block = True
            open_boxes -= 1        
            print('Computer is thinking...')
            print('Computer blocks your winning move.')
            board[2] = opp_letter
            show_board()
            human_first()

def human_first():
    can_block = False
    global open_boxes
    if open_boxes > 0:
        while True:
            move = input('Please pick a number from 1 - 9: ')
            if move.isdigit():
                move = int(move) - 1
            else:
                print('Sorry, please pick a number from 1 - 9: ')
                human_first()
            winner = False

            if board[move] != 'x' and board[move] != 'o':
                board[move] = human_letter
                open_boxes -= 1
                show_board()

            else:
                print('\n')
                print('Sorry that space is taken. Try again')
                print('\n')
                show_board()
                human_first()

            if checkAll(human_letter) == True:
                winner = True
                print ("--HUMAN WINS--")
                print ('\n')
                play_again()
                break;

            computer_move()

            if checkAll(opp_letter) == True:
                winner = True
                print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
                print ('\n')
                play_again()
                break;
    else:
        print('--DRAW--')
        play_again()

def computer_first():
    global open_boxes
    if open_boxes > 0:
        computer_move()
        while True:
            move = input('Please pick a number from 1 - 9: ')
            if move.isdigit():
                move = int(move) - 1
            else:
                print('Sorry, please pick a number from 1 - 9: ')
                human_first()

            winner = False

            if board[move] != 'x' and board[move] != 'o':
                board[move] = human_letter
                open_boxes -= 1
                show_board()
            else:
                print('\n')
                print('Sorry that space is taken. Try again')
                print('\n')
                show_board()
                human_first()

            if checkAll(human_letter) == True:
                winner = True
                print ("--HUMAN WINS--")
                print ('\n')
                play_again()
                break;

            computer_move()

            if checkAll(opp_letter) == True:
                winner = True
                print ("--COMPUTER WINS--")
                print ('\n')
                play_again()
                break;
    else:
        print('--DRAW--')
        play_again()

def who_goes_first():
    global board
    global open_boxes
    open_boxes = 9
    print ('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!This is your game board: ')
    print ('\n')
    show_board()
    choose_letter()
    print ('\n')
    print('The first player will be chosen at random.')
    print('...')
    first = random.randint(0,1)
    if first == 1:
        print('Human goes first')
        human_first()
    else:
        print('Computer goes first')
        computer_first()

def play_again():
    global board
    board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    print('Do you want to play again? Y/N: ')
    answer = input().lower()
    if answer in ('y','ye','yes'):
        who_goes_first()
    elif answer in ('n','no'):
        print('Hope you enjoyed the game!')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Sorry, I didn\'t get that..')
        play_again()



who_goes_first()
```

Comment: Two big things come to mind. 1) don't use globals-  pass everything as function arguments and return values, it will make it easier to reset things.  2) use `board` for display purposes only. Its difficult to check anything more than move validity using the literal game board matrix. Instead, keep 8 lists (one for each potential 3-in-a-row), and remove elements as moves are made.